# Помогите, не знаю почему выдает ошибку. Ошибка:TypeError: vid is null

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите, не знаю, почему выдает ошибку.

**Ошибка:**

> TypeError: vid is null в FireFox

На локальном сервере все работало, при переноске на сайт выдает эту ошибку. Скрипт подключен через тему в ворд-пресс.

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
function doclick() { 
    vid.play();
    var http_request = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
    http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
    http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');}
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
    try {http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
    catch (e) {
    try {http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
    catch (e) {}
    }
    }
    if (!http_request) {return false;}
    http_request.open('GET','/ClicksCounterVlad_File.php?go=yes', true);
    http_request.send();
    }

function pauseVid() { 
    vid.pause();}
```

```html
<div>
 <audio controls id="myVideo" loop="loop">
 <source src="http://radio.vosbs.ru:8000/live">
     Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
 </audio>
 <button id="playVid1" onclick="doclick()" type="button"></button>
 <button id="pauseVid1" onclick="pauseVid()" type="button"></button>

</div>
```

Comment: var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); -эту строку надо было поместить в функцию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код совершенно рабочий. Скорее всего, вы прикрутили script с кодом раньше, чем разметку HTML, поэтому при выполнении он не может найти элемент с id="myVideo", поскольку в DOM-модели он еще не прописан. Самое простое - вставьте script после div, и все будет. И в теге button желательно указать название кнопки...

Answer (score 0):

`var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");` -эту строку надо было поместить в функцию.